# "ПорчеННый игрой" — нужно ли удваивать Н?

Tags: орфография, причастия, выбор-варианта, удвоенные-согласные

Как правильно: *порче**н**ый игрой* или *порче**нн**ый игрой* — о человеке, которого испортила игра?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть зависимое слово в творит. пад., значит, страдательное причастие - НН- порченный игрой.

Answer (score 1):

О человеке, которого **испортила** игра, — **испорченный** игрой.
О человеке, которого **портила** игра, — **порченный** игрой.

Answer (score 1):

***НН*** пишется в полных причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных, если есть зависимое слово:
**кошенный** [когда?] **в** прошлую **пятницу** луг;
**писанный** [чем?] масляными **красками** портрет.

[Правописание причастий](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/691-383_pravopisanie_prichastii.html) (часть третья)

1. В орфографическом словаре:
   [порченный](https://orthographic.academic.ru/59468), *прич.*
   *А у нас дама, **порченная литературой**, старается жить, одеваясь в ризы мечты* (Горький).
2. *Так уж вышло, что я СКС видел только на плакате в армейском учебном классе при тире, да и то шибко не приглядывался, потому как плакат был старый, выцветший и **порченный плесенью*** (Б. Громов. Терской фронт).